# Building Speech Recognition for a closed vocabulary

Tags: cmusphinx

I can create voice recognition for my limited set of words using the following link.
http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html

But how do I give feedback to the language model to train better for my voice.
For example, the phonetic values in .dic files are for american accent (I want to train it to indian accent).

Answer (score 1):

Language model has nothing to do with voice, it operates with words. Use [SphinxTrain](http://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/SphinxTrain/) to tailor the acoustic model to the accent you need and read how to [adapt existing model](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt) or [create new one](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam).